# Match list values to dict and return key/value pairs in new dict

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list that represents the values of a dictionary. I am trying to parse the dictionary looking for values that are also in my list and creating a new dictionary from this that contains only the matched values:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = {"aye":1, "bee":2, "cee":3, "dee":4, "eee":5}

new_dict = dict((k, v) for k, v in b.iteritems() if k in a)
print new_dict
```

My desired output should look like this:

```
new_dict = {"aye":1, "bee":2, "cee":3}
```

However, all I am getting back is:

```
{}
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if v in a`?

Comment: `dict((k, v) for k, v in b.iteritems() if k in a)` is Python 2.6 syntax.  Unless you happen to be using that old version, the modern solution is to use a dictionary comprehension: `{k:v for k, v in b.iteritems() if k in a}`.

Comment: If performance is important to you, `a` should be a `set`.

Answer (score 4):

`k` represents the keys and `v` the values

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = {"aye":1, "bee":2, "cee":3, "dee":4, "eee":5}
>>> new_dict = dict((k, v) for k, v in b.iteritems() if v in a)
>>> print new_dict
{'aye': 1, 'cee': 3, 'bee': 2}
```

So therefore to achieve what you want, you have to do `if v in a` instead.